# QueryStore plan forcing limitations

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, execution-plan, full-text-search, query-store

I have a `DELETE` statement running against a table with a full-text indexed column, a handful of foreign keys with `cascade` enabled. It looks like this:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.STUDENTS WHERE STUDENTID=@STUDENTID
```

Occasionally a plan is compiled which includes very high row estimates for all index operations, such that the `DELETE` takes a very long time and causes locking.

I have attempted to force a good plan in QueryStore but this doesn't actually work,  showing `last forced plan failure description` of `NO_PLAN`.

I have ensured that there are no schema changes that could be invalidating the plan.

Looking at the execution plan, I see that the `DELETE` involves a join to a system table holding the FT index:

[image]

Does this join to the FT index mean that plan-forcing is not supported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When looking at the [plan-forcing limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-plan-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#plan-forcing-limitations) one of the bullet points is:

> Distributed query or full-text operations

**However**, this limitation does not mean that a delete should fail the plan forcing.

Consider these 4 queries, two `SELECT` statements and two `DELETE` statements on a table with a fulltext index on the `val` column:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  dbo.fulltextindexed;

SELECT val 
FROM  dbo.fulltextindexed
WHERE CONTAINS(val, N'WOW');

DELETE top(1)  
FROM dbo.fulltextindexed;

DELETE top(1)  
FROM dbo.fulltextindexed
WHERE id <500 and id > -1;
```

The only query that is failing is the 2nd one, which is using the `CONTAINS` statement:

[image]

With the failure reason being `DQ_NO_FORCING_SUPPORTED`.

The plans for the two delete statements, which also show the same `clustered index merge` operators get forced:

[image]

[This source](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/determining-happens-force-execution-plan-via-query-store/) gives more information on `DQ_NO_FORCING_SUPPORTED`:

> Cannot execute query because plan conflicts with use of distributed
>   query or full-text operations

**To answer the question**

> Does this join to the FT index mean that plan-forcing is not
>   supported?

My answer would be that this is not the reason as you should see the `DQ_NO_FORCING_SUPPORTED` instead of the `NO_PLAN` error. 
The reason could be due to another limitation rendering the plan invalid, index changes, added foreign keys, ....

---

**Extra tests**

When adding a table and creating a foreign key with on delete cascade that references the table used in the queries above.We would expect the delete to fail since we cannot use the forced plan any longer.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.fulltexreference(id int identity(1,1) primary key not null, t1id int, val varchar(max));
ALTER TABLE dbo.fulltexreference add constraint FK_test foreign key(t1id) REFERENCES dbo.fulltextindexed(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

As expected, we get the `NO_PLAN` on the two delete statements
[image]

Re-forcing the plans gives us salvation:

[image]

And removes the `NO_PLAN` issue

[image]

*The same is true for a table with a fulltext index that has a foreign key (with on delete cascade) that references the main table where the delete query is running on.*

**Regarding the high / low estimates**

If the delete is not executed that much, adding `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` could help with the high row estimates as this can give you a better estimation due to the optimizer 'seeing' the variable at runtime.

Posting a different question with the query plan might bring up a different workaround / solution.